# Why do I get 'Binary logging not possible.' on my MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, linux, virtualbox, toad

When I started up my MySQL server today and try to do some changes using [Toad for Mysql](http://www.quest.com/toad-for-mysql/), I get this message:

> MySQL Database Error
>
> Binary logging not possible. Message: Transaction level
>   'READ-COMMITTED' in InnoDB is not safe for binlog mode 'STATEMENT'

I have no idea what this means. I'm running Mysql on VirtualBox with Ubuntu 11.x.

Has anyone run into this problem before?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [ERROR 1598 (HY000): Binary Logging not Possible. Message: Transaction Level READ-COMMITTED in InnoDB is not Safe for Binlog Mode STATEMENT](http://wiki.ispirer.com/sqlways/troubleshooting-guide/mysql/import/binlog_mode_statement):

> There are several solutions for the issue:
>
> - You need to change the binlog mode to either **ROW** or **MIXED** in order to run the load of the data into the database
>
>   ```
>   mysql> SET GLOBAL binlog_format = 'ROW';
>   ```
> - If you are not planning to use your MySQL server for the replication consider turning the binary logging off by removing the
>     option `--log-bin` from the command options for the mysqld utility
>     starting the MySQL server.

Comment: I did that last bit. I had turned it ON because I was trying to debug some issues.

Comment: setting the binlog_format did not resolve my problem. any other advice as to what it could be?

Comment: actually, the `SET GLOBAL` just didn't work. i had to set 'binlog_format' in /etc/my.cnf and restart mysql.