# CFWheels - Error inserting record with save() method

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, railo, cfwheels

I get the following error on Railo with CFWheels when using save():

> Cannot execute statement: impossible to write to binary log since
>   BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT and at least one table uses a storage engine
>   limited to row-based logging. InnoDB is limited to row-logging when
>   transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED or READ UNCOMMITTED.

Here's is my code:

```
<cfset params.vote['voteUserID'] = params.link.linkUserID />
<cfset params.vote['voteLinkID'] = params.link.linkID />
<cfset params.vote['voteType'] = 1 />

<cfset vote = model("vote").new(params.vote) />
<cfset vote.save() />
```

Any idea what's going on? I have another insert statement that's similar and it works fine. I suspect it's something to do with a seTting in my database table? I'm using MySQL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it seems changing the storage engine on the database table from "InnoDB" to "MyISAM" solved the issue. Perhaps CFWheels doesn't play nicely with "InnoDB" for some reason; perhaps someone could add a comment about why that is?

Comment: Many of CFWheels's ORM features rely on a DB engine that can track transactions. (For example, nested properties and callbacks will roll back the transaction if they break a validation or callback chain.) I'd recommend seeing if you can resolve the issue without switching to the transactionless-MyISAM.

Comment: So you recommend actually using InnoDB for wheels?

Comment: Yes. It helps keep referential integrity with your data.

Comment: Do you think when the error says this: "...at least one table uses a storage engine limited to row-based logging" it could mean that I need to also select InnoDB as the storage engine for ALL tables in my database? Some were already MyISAM and this table in particular was InnoDB.

Comment: Also possible. Did you try changing them?

Comment: I haven't yet, but I will at some point today and I will update this thread.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using replication in this particular environment? Looks like the `BINLOG_FORMAT` setting is related to replication.

I'd recommend looking up where `BINLOG_FORMAT` is set in MySQL, research what the various options are, and change it to something that is suitable for your scenario.

See this SO answer: [Why do I get 'Binary logging not possible.' on my MySQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665535/)